# Pycharm debugger skips breakpoints after specific line of code - why?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm new to pycharm and so far my impression of the debugger is that it's marverlous! However, it behaves weird in my code and I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

If I set a breakpoint to these lines of code and then press "step over" or "step into my code" it runs until the end ignoring all other upcoming breakpoints. Any idea what I do wrong? Breakpoints before that line work perfectly fine.

```
    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit
```

**my code**

You need to pip install *deap*, *efel* and *brian2* for the code to run.

```
# DEAP
# https://github.com/DEAP/deap/tree/54b83e2cc7a73be7657cb64b01033a31584b891d

# import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import loadmat
import random, numpy, os, efel, scipy, math, time, array, json
from deap import algorithms, base, creator, tools, benchmarks
from deap.benchmarks.tools import diversity, convergence  # , hypervolume
from machine_hh_model_v02 import brian_hh_model

# parallel processing
# from scoop import futures
parallel_processing = "no"

# Starting values
channels = {"ENa": 65,
            "EK": -90,
            "El": -70,
            "ECa": 120,
            "gNa": 0.05,
            "gK": 0.005,
            "gL": 1e-4,
            "gM": 8e-5,
            "gCa": 1e-5}

# Boundaries
bounds = {"ENa": [50, 70],
          "EK": [-100, -80],
          "El": [-50, -100],
          "ECa": [100, 120],
          "gNa": [0, 1],
          "gK": [0, 1],
          "gL": [0, 1],
          "gM": [0, 1],
          "gCa": [0, 1]}
low, up = [x[0] for x in bounds.values()], [x[1] for x in bounds.values()]

# Set parameters
ext = 2.5  # external current stimulation [nA]
num_gen = 2  # number of generations
num_parents = 40  # number of parents
num_params = len(channels)  # number of parameters to optimize
prob_crossover = 0.9  # probability that crossover takes place


# How to generate individuals
def initIndividual(container, sigma):
    return container(random.gauss(x, sigma) for x in channels.values())


# CREATOR
# http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part1.html

# The create() function takes at least two arguments, a name for the newly created class and a base class. Any
# subsequent argument becomes an attribute of the class. Neg. weights relate to minizing, pos. weight to maximizing
# problems.
# -- define fitness problem (which params are min./max. problems with which weight)
creator.create("FitnessMulti", base.Fitness, weights=tuple(numpy.ones(num_params) * -1))

# Next we will create the class Individual, which will inherit the class list and contain our previously defined
# FitnessMulti class in its fitness attribute. Note that upon creation all our defined classes will be part of the
# creator container and can be called directly.
# -- associate fitness problem to individuals, that are going to be created
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMulti)

# TOOLBOX
# http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_onemax.html
# http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/tools.html#module-deap.tools

# All the objects we will use on our way, an individual, the population, as well as all functions, operators, and
# arguments will be stored in a DEAP container called Toolbox. It contains two methods for adding and removing content,
# register() and unregister().
toolbox = base.Toolbox()

# The newly introduced register() method takes at least two arguments: an alias and a function. Toolbox.attr_bool(),
# when called, will draw a random integer between -100 and 100. Toolbox.attr_float(), when called, will draw a random
# floating point number.
# -- how to generate values for each individual
# toolbox.register("attr_float", random.uniform, -100, 100)
# toolbox.register("attr_float", lambda: [random.gauss(x, 5) for x in channels.values()])

# Our individuals will be generated using the function initRepeat(). Its first argument is a container class, the
# Individual one we defined in the previous section. This container will be filled using the method attr_float(),
# provided as second argument, and will contain 10 integers, as specified using the third argument. When called, the
# individual() method will thus return an individual initialized with what would be returned by calling the attr_float()
# method 100 times.
# -- how and how many individuals to create
# toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.attr_float, num_params)
toolbox.register("individual", initIndividual, creator.Individual, sigma=1)

# Finally, the population() method uses the same paradigm.
# -- how and how many parents to create
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

# LOAD EXPERIMENTAL DATA
# set path
# mainpath = r'C:\OwnCloud\Masterarbeit'  # mainpath
# pathfit = os.path.join(mainpath, r'fitness_params')  # fitness files
# os.chdir(os.path.join(mainpath, pathfit))  # change directory

# load fitness file
# xl       = pd.ExcelFile('fitness.xlsx')              # load excel file
# xl_mean  = xl.parse("median")                        # load sheet 'mean' containing mean/median values
# xl_var   = xl.parse("quartile-to-median distance")   # load sheet 'std containing std/quantiles values
xl_mean = pd.read_json("median")
xl_var = pd.read_json("distance")


########################
############ SOMETHING IS WRONG HERE
########################

# EFEL: median
def efel_stats(features):
    # get latency of first spike
    if features['peak_time'].any():
        features['first_peak_time'] = features['peak_time'][0]
        del features['peak_time']
    # get median
    for key, val in features.items():
        if val is None or numpy.isnan(val) or not val:
            features[key] = 9999
        else:
            features[key] = scipy.nanmedian(val)
    # get median
    # if features['Spikecount'] == 0:
    #    for key, val in f#eatures.items( ):
    #        features[key] = 9999
    # else:
    #    for key, val in features.items():
    #        features[key] = scipy.nanmedian(val)
    return features


# ERROR FUNCTION
# The returned value must be iterable and of a length equal to the number of objectives (weights).
def error_function(external_current, indi, xl_mean=xl_mean, xl_var=xl_var):
    # output variable
    allerrors = []

    # BRIAN: run model
    stim_start, stim_duration = 500, 1000
    voltage, time = brian_hh_model(1, 0, stim_start, stim_duration,
                                   ENa=indi[0], EK=indi[1], El=indi[2], ECa=indi[3], gNa=indi[4], gK=indi[5],
                                   gL=indi[6], gM=indi[7], gCa=indi[8])
    # EFEL: extract features and get median
    feature_names = ['Spikecount', 'peak_voltage', 'min_AHP_values', 'AP_begin_voltage', 'spike_half_width',
                     'voltage_base', 'steady_state_voltage_stimend',
                     'AP_begin_time', 'peak_time']
    trace = {'T': time, 'V': voltage, 'stim_start': [stim_start], 'stim_end': [stim_start + stim_duration]}
    features = efel.getFeatureValues([trace], feature_names)[0]
    features = efel_stats(features)

    # # ERROR FUNCTION: get error value
    for feature, value in features.items():
        # median for one external current (experimental data)
        experiment_vals = xl_mean.loc[xl_mean['stimulus'] == external_current, feature].values[0]
        error = float(abs(value - experiment_vals))

        # my model can produce the same, less or more #spikes, peakvoltage, ...
        if value == experiment_vals:
            error = 0.
        elif value < experiment_vals:
            error = error / float(xl_var.loc[xl_var['stimulus'] == external_current, feature].values[0][0])
        elif value > experiment_vals:
            error = error / float(xl_var.loc[xl_var['stimulus'] == external_current, feature].values[0][1])

        # append error value of this feature
        allerrors.append(error)

    return allerrors


# GENETIC OPERATORS
# Within DEAP there are two ways of using operators. We can 1) simply call a function from the tools module or
# 2) register it with its arguments in a toolbox, as we have already seen for our initialization methods. The second
# option allows us to to easily switch between the operators if desired.
# see http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/tools.html#module-deap.tools

# Crossover
# Register the crossover function to the toolbox
# tools.cxOnePoint --> one point crossover
# tools.cxTwoPoint --> two-point crossover
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxSimulatedBinary, eta=20.0)

# Mutation
# Register the mutation function to the toolbox
# tools.mutGaussian --> applies a gaussian mutation of mean mu and standard deviation sigma on the input individual. The indpb argument is the probability of each attribute to be mutated.
# tools.mutPolynomialBounded --> Polynomial mutation as implemented in original NSGA-II algorithm in C by Deb.
# toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutPolynomialBounded, eta=20, low=low, up=up, indpb=1.0/num_params)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutGaussian, mu=0, sigma=2, indpb=0.9)

# Selection
# tools.sortNondominated(individuals, k, first_front_only=False) --> Sort the first k individuals into different nondomination levels using the “Fast Nondominated Sorting Approach” proposed by Deb et al., see [Deb2002].
# tools.sortLogNondominated(individuals, k, first_front_only=False) --> Sort individuals in pareto non-dominated fronts using the Generalized Reduced Run-Time Complexity Non-Dominated Sorting Algorithm presented by Fortin et al. (2013).
toolbox.register("select", tools.selNSGA2)

# Evaluation
# Register error function in the toolbox.
# The evaluation will be performed by calling the alias "evaluate".
# toolbox.register("evaluate", error_function, ext, model_vals)


# ALGORITHM
# Now that everything is ready, we can start to write our own algorithm. It is usually done in a main function.

if parallel_processing=="yes":
    toolbox.register("map", futures.map)


def main():
    # register statistics to the toolbox to maintain stats of the evolution
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean, axis=0)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std, axis=0)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min, axis=0)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max, axis=0)
    logbook = tools.Logbook()
    logbook.header = "gen", "evals", "min"

    ###
    ### NSGA-II algorithm as in "Deb 2002: A Fast and Elitist Multiobjective Genetic Algorithm: NSGA-II"
    ### https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/nsga2.py
    ###

    # create random parent population pop
    pop = toolbox.population(n=num_parents)

    # register error function
    toolbox.register("evaluate", error_function, ext)

    # evaluate parent population
    invalid_ind = [ind for ind in pop if not ind.fitness.valid]
    fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
    for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit

    # assign crowding distance to the individuals, no actual selection is done
    pop = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))

    # print logbook
    record = stats.compile(pop)
    logbook.record(gen=0, evals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
    print(logbook.stream)
    # print(record)

    # Begin the generational process
    for gen in range(1, num_gen):

        # increase the variance in my population
        offspring = tools.selTournamentDCD(pop, len(pop))
        # I have no idea why
        offspring = [toolbox.clone(ind) for ind in offspring]

        # crossover
        for ind1, ind2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]):
            if random.random() <= prob_crossover:
                toolbox.mate(ind1, ind2)

            # mutation
            toolbox.mutate(ind1)
            toolbox.mutate(ind2)
            del ind1.fitness.values, ind2.fitness.values

        # Fitness
        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        # Select the next generation population
        pop = toolbox.select(pop + offspring, num_parents)
        record = stats.compile(pop)
        logbook.record(gen=gen, evals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
        print(logbook.stream)
        # print(record)

    # print("Final population hypervolume is %f" % hypervolume(pop, [11.0, 11.0]))

    return pop, logbook

    # create pareto front (all non-dominated individuals that ever lived)
    # pareto = tools.ParetoFront()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pop, logbook = main()
    print(logbook)
    print("POPULATION", pop)
    for indi in pop:
        stim_start, stim_duration = 500, 1000
        voltage, time = brian_hh_model(1, 1, stim_start, stim_duration,
                                       ENa=indi[0], EK=indi[1], El=indi[2], ECa=indi[3], gNa=indi[4], gK=indi[5],
                                       gL=indi[6], gM=indi[7], gCa=indi[8])
        print("INDIVIDUAL ", indi)
```

**machine_hh_model_v02**

```
# brian user guide
# http://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/2.0rc/user/index.html

from brian2 import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style()

def brian_hh_model(input_current, plotflag, stim_start, stim_duration, **parameter):

    # C++ standalone mode
    # At the beginning of the script, i.e. after the import statements, add:
    # set_device('cpp_standalone', build_on_run=False)

    # ********
    # Handling units
    # You can generate a physical quantity by multiplying a scalar or vector value with its physical unit:
    # tau = 20*ms --> 20. ms
    # rates = [10, 20, 30] * Hz --> [ 10.  20.  30.] Hz

    # Most Brian functions will also complain about non-specified or incorrect units:
    # G = NeuronGroup(10, 'dv/dt = -v/tau: volt', dt=0.5) --> "dt" has wrong dimensions, dimensions were (1) (s)

    # Directly get the unitless value of a state variable by appending an underscore to the name
    # print(rates_) --> [ 10.  20.  30.]
    # ********


    # Default parameters
    # Set default parameters
    default = {"ENa": 65, "EK": -90, "El": -70, "ECa": 120, "gNa": 0.05, "gK": 0.005, "gL": 1e-4, "gM": 8e-5,
               "gCa": 1e-5}

    # Use default parameter, if not defined as an input parameter
    for key, val in default.items():
        if key not in parameter:
            parameter[key] = val


    # Parameters
    # Extract parameters that were given as an input (as a dictionary).

    d    = 96 * umetre                           # 79.8 umetre
    area = d*d*3.141
    Cm   = 1*ufarad*cm**-2 * area               # 1 ufarad

    ENa  = parameter["ENa"]*mV
    EK   = parameter["EK"]*mV
    El   = parameter["El"]*mV
    ECa  = parameter["ECa"]*mV

    g_na = parameter["gNa"]*siemens*cm**-2 * area         # 0.05 siemens
    g_kd = parameter["gK"]*siemens*cm**-2 * area          # 0.005 siemens
    gl   = parameter["gL"]*siemens*cm**-2 * area           # 1e-4 siemens
    gm   = parameter["gM"]*siemens*cm**-2 * area         # 8e-5 siemens
    gCa  = parameter["gCa"]*siemens*cm**-2 * area

    tauMax = 4000 * ms

    VT = -63*mV



    # Equations
    # Define both state variables and continuous-updates on these variables through differential equations. An Equation is
    # a set of single lines in a string:
    # 1. dx/dt = f : unit (differential equation)
    # 2.     x = f : unit (subexpression)
    # 3.         x : unit (parameter)
    # There are three special units, "1" -> floating point number, "boolean" and "integer"

    # Some special variables are defined: t, dt (time) and xi (white noise). Some other variable names (e.g. _pre) are
    # forbidden. Flags -- dx/dt = f : unit (constant), parameter will not be changed during a run.


    # The model
    eqs = Equations('''

    Im = gm * p * (v-EK) : amp
    Ica = gCa * q*q * r * (v-ECa) : amp

    dv/dt = (gl*(El-v) - g_na*(m*m*m)*h*(v-ENa) - g_kd*(n*n*n*n)*(v-EK) - Im - Ica + I)/Cm : volt


    dm/dt = 0.32*(mV**-1)*(13.*mV-v+VT)/
      (exp((13.*mV-v+VT)/(4.*mV))-1.)/ms*(1-m)-0.28*(mV**-1)*(v-VT-40.*mV)/
      (exp((v-VT-40.*mV)/(5.*mV))-1.)/ms*m : 1
    dn/dt = 0.032*(mV**-1)*(15.*mV-v+VT)/
      (exp((15.*mV-v+VT)/(5.*mV))-1.)/ms*(1.-n)-.5*exp((10.*mV-v+VT)/(40.*mV))/ms*n : 1
    dh/dt = 0.128*exp((17.*mV-v+VT)/(18.*mV))/ms*(1.-h)-4./(1+exp((40.*mV-v+VT)/(5.*mV)))/ms*h : 1

    # K+ current
    dp/dt = (1/(1+exp(-(v-VT+35.*mV)/(10.*mV))) - p) / (tauMax / (3.3 * exp((v - VT + 35.*mV)/(20.*mV) + exp(-(v - VT + 35.*mV)/(20.*mV))))) : 1

    # Ca2+ current
    dq/dt = 0.055*(mV**-1) * (-27.*mV - v) / (exp((-27.*mV - v) / (3.8*mV)) - 1.)/ms * (1.-q) - 0.94*exp((-75.*mV - v) / (17.*mV))/ms*q : 1
    dr/dt = 0.000457 * exp((-13.*mV - v) / (50.*mV))/ms * (1.-r) - 0.0065 / (1. + exp((-15.*mV - v) / (28.*mV)))/ms*r : 1

    I : amp
    ''')


    # NeuronGroup
    # The core of every simulation is a NeuronGroup, a group of neurons that share the same equations defining their
    # properties. Minimum inputs are "number of neurons" and "model description in the form of equations". Threshold and
    # refractoriness are only used for emiting spikes. To make a neuron non-excitable for a certain time period after a
    # spike, the refractory keyword can be used.
    # G = NeuronGroup(10, 'dv/dt = -v/tau : volt', threshold='v > -50*mV', reset='v = -70*mV', refractory=5*ms)

    # Dictionary
    # You can set multiple initial values at once using a dictionary and the Group.get_states() and Group.set_states()
    # methods.
    # initial_values = {'v': 1, 'tau': 10*ms}
    # group.set_states(initial_values)
    # group.v[:] --> 1)
    # states = group.get_states()
    # states['v'] --> 1)

    group   = NeuronGroup(1, eqs, method="exponential_euler")
    group.v = El
    group.I = 0*nA


    # Recording
    # Recording variables during a simulation is done with “monitor” objects. Specifically, spikes are recorded with
    # SpikeMonitor, the time evolution of variables with StateMonitor and the firing rate of a population of neurons with
    # PopulationRateMonitor. You can get all the stored values in a monitor with the Group.get_states().

    # In this example, we record two variables v and u, and record from indices 0, 10 and 100 --> three neurons.
    # G = NeuronGroup(...)
    # M = StateMonitor(G, ('v', 'u'), record=[0, 10, 100])
    # M.v[1] will return the values for the second recorded neuron which is the neuron with the index 10.

    M = StateMonitor(group, 'v', record=0)


    # Run the model
    # The command run(100*ms) runs the simulation for 100 ms.
    run(stim_start*ms)
    group.I[0] = input_current*nA  # current injection at one end
    run(stim_duration*ms)
    group.I = 0*nA
    run(stim_start*ms)

    # C++ standalone mode
    # After the last run() call, call device.build() explicitly:
    # device.build(directory='output', compile=True, run=True, debug=False)


    # Timing
    # profiling_summary(show=5) -- show the 5 objects that took the longest
    # profiling_summary(show=2)


    # Output
    time = M.t/ms
    voltage = M.v[0]/mV


    # plot output
    if plotflag:
        plt.plot(time, voltage)
        xlabel('Time [ms]')
        ylabel('Membrane potential [mV]')
        plt.show()

    # For multiple calls
    # device.reinit()
    # device.activate()

    return (voltage, time)

#brian_hh_model(1, 1, 500, 1000, ENa=65, EK=-90, El=-70, ECa=120, gNa=0.05, gK=0.005, gL=1e-4, gM=8e-5, gCa=1e-5)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!